# Simple Integration - ZohoCRM, HighriseHQ, PipelineDeals

Tags: crm, zoho

I've looked at these three CRM systems for some very simple lead management, they have the usual REST get info out, put info in data sync api, some have colour changing stuff but aside from that its seems impossible to integrate.

Take HighRiseHQ or ZohoCRM, all I want to do is add a button to the page that does an ajax post into my company system. If they give just one line, just one measly line in header, I can inject a script src="myurl/customise-zoho-crm.js" which manipulate the dom on ready, pull a few bits of info needed, injects a button and does ajax on hit. But no hosted CRM I can see allows this, unless you hit ms crm or salesforce..

I thought about greasemonkey as only 5 users, but its feel so dirty, but then to get basic contact/lead management is waste of my dev time. Due to sales calcs etc.. it does need to tie (or post into my backend system).. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the email mattcodes, thought I'd jump onto SO to reply to you.

Unfortunately, I don't think the Simple Sales Tracking API will enable the .js file either.

The API itself has good coverage and access to data.  Often what's available through an API can be quite limited.

Anyways, have a look at the API details page. Any questions or feedback, just drop us another note.  http://www.simplesalestracking.com/api.aspx

If you're using .net, there's a dll api wrapper library ready to go. Also a c# sample application.

Comment: Thanks John, Im more interested in customization the UI behaviour though, is there any reason one doesnt allow savvy administrators of crm install to include their own JS file or css file... I think this would open a world possibilities

Answer (score 0):

Code injection thru a browser extension is what you're looking for.

Either with Chrome or Firefox, an extension can interact with opened tabs DOM, crawl into it and change it's structure on the fly.